# Deduce template return type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, return-type-deduction

Currently I try to write a function `retrieveKeys()` which gives me the keys of a `std::map` and stores it in some `std::container`. The function shall be generic in two ways:

- Accept `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` as parameter type.
- Return the keys in a user defined container, e. g. `std::vector` or `std::deque` (the container has to supports a `push_back()` method).

Currently the use of this function works as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> testMap;
std::map<int, int> testMap2;

std::vector<int> keys1 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap);    
std::deque<int> keys2 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap);
std::vector<int> keys3 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap2);
std::deque<int> keys4 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap2);
```

With the following function:

```
template<template<typename...> typename KeyContainer, typename... KeyContainer_Rest,
         template<typename...> typename MapContainer, typename K, typename V, typename... MapContainer_Rest>
inline KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> retrieveKeys(const MapContainer<K, V, MapContainer_Rest...>& map)
{
    KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> keys;

    for (const auto& m : map)
    {
        keys.push_back(m.first);
    }

    return keys;
}
```

It would be nice if I would not have to write the return type explicitly. But when I try something like

```
std::vector<int> keys1_ = retrieveKeys(testMap);
/*
error: no matching function for call to 'retrieveKeys'
std::vector<int> keys1_ = retrieveKeys(testMap);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
*/
```

I get the mentioned error when compiling with clang 3.6 (C++17).

So my question is: Is it possible to rewrite the function so that the return type can be reduced by the compiler?

Here again the complete code for easy copying:

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>

template<template<typename...> typename KeyContainer, typename... KeyContainer_Rest,
         template<typename...> typename MapContainer, typename K, typename V, typename... MapContainer_Rest>
inline KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> retrieveKeys(const MapContainer<K, V, MapContainer_Rest...>& map)
{
    KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> keys;

    for (const auto& m : map)
    {
        keys.push_back(m.first);
    }

    return keys;
}

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> testMap;
    std::map<int, int> testMap2;

    std::vector<int> keys1 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap);    
    std::deque<int> keys2 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap);
    std::vector<int> keys3 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap2);
    std::deque<int> keys4 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap2);

    //std::vector<int> keys1_ = retrieveKeys(testMap);
    /*
    error: no matching function for call to 'retrieveKeys'
    std::vector<int> keys1_ = retrieveKeys(testMap);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
    */
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <typename K, typename M>
struct ReturnTypeDeducer
{
    const M& map;

    ReturnTypeDeducer(const M& m) : map(m) {}

    template <template <typename...> typename KeyContainer, typename... KeyContainer_Rest>
    operator KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...>() &&
    {
        KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> keys;
        for (const auto& m : map)
        {
            keys.push_back(m.first);
        }
        return keys;
    }
};

template <template <typename...> typename MapContainer, typename K, typename V, typename... MapContainer_Rest>
inline ReturnTypeDeducer<K, MapContainer<K, V, MapContainer_Rest...>> retrieveKeys(const MapContainer<K, V, MapContainer_Rest...>& map)
{
    return map;
}

int main() 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> testMap;
    std::map<int, int> testMap2;

    std::vector<int> keys1 = retrieveKeys(testMap);    
    std::deque<int> keys2 = retrieveKeys(testMap);
    std::vector<int> keys3 = retrieveKeys(testMap2);
    std::deque<int> keys4 = retrieveKeys(testMap2);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d77d321bfe09c822)

Comment: but this does not work with `auto` at the call site, instead it relies on implicit conversions

Comment: @TemplateRex Well, the information has to come from *somewhere*...either the target type must be known, or you must use explicit template arguments.

Comment: @T.C. sure, but still, ingenious as this is, I think it's bad style to encourage implicit conversions.

Comment: Wow that solution really is sophisticated! Personally I find `std::vector<int> keys1 = retrieveKeys(testMap);` more readable than `auto keys1 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap);`. What is the concept name behind the && at the end of the conversion operator (which I had to remove in msvc2015 to get it working btw)?

Comment: @Milania That ref-qualifier makes sure the conversion operator is used only when `ReturnTypeDeducer` is an rvalue (immediately resulting from a call to `retrieveKeys`), so as to reduce the risk of making conversion from a dangling reference. Consider this code: `auto foo = retrieveKeys(std::map<int,int>{});`. Now, `foo` stores a dangling reference, but thanks to this ref-qualifier you won't accidentaly use it like `std::vector<int> v = foo;`

Comment: Do we need the constructor for the functor? can the argument be directly passed to `operator()`?

Answer (score 3):

No. There's no way for the compiler to tell what the return type should be because it has no information it can use to determine that (you can call `retrieveKeys()` outside of the context of immediately assigning it to a variable of the type you want).

However, you can reduce the code duplication by using `auto`:

```
auto keys1 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap);    
auto keys2 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap);
auto keys3 = retrieveKeys<std::vector>(testMap2);
auto keys4 = retrieveKeys<std::deque>(testMap2);
```

Comment: and also use `auto` in the return type of `retrieveKeys`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no return type deduction **at the call site** because the compiler would lack the necessary context. Compare with e.g. `std::make_unique`:

```
auto derived_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>(args); // have to specify return type
```

In general, template argument-deduction works on, well, the supplied template arguments. Supplying an out-parameter will deduce everything

```
template<class InputParam, class OutputParam>
void copy(InputParam const& src, OutParam& dst) { /* bla */ }

// call as:
InputParam src = /* fill */;
OutputParam dst; // empty
copy(src, dst)   // template arguments deduced from supplied src, dst
```

In contrast, without it, you have to explicitly supply the template argument:

```
template<class InputParam, class OutputParam>
OutputParam copy(InputParam const& src) { OutputParam x; /* bla */ return x; }

// call as: 
InputParam src = /* fill */;
auto dst = copy<OutputParam>(src); // InputParam deduced from src, supply OutputParam template argument
```

In contrast, at the **point of definition**, C++14 does have return type deduction, so you could write

```
template<template<typename...> typename KeyContainer, typename... KeyContainer_Rest,
         template<typename...> typename MapContainer, typename K, typename V, typename... MapContainer_Rest>
auto // <-- here
retrieveKeys(const MapContainer<K, V, MapContainer_Rest...>& map)
{
    KeyContainer<K, KeyContainer_Rest...> keys;

    for (const auto& m : map)
    {
        keys.push_back(m.first);
    }

    return keys; // compiler will deduce return-type of retrieveKeys from this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
An example of how you can use container::key_type

template <class CONTAINER>
std::vector <typename CONTAINER::key_type>
retrieveKeys(CONTAINER container)
{
    std::vector <typename CONTAINER::key_type> keys;
    for (auto itr : container)
    {
        keys.push_back(itr.first);
    }
    return keys;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    typedef std::map <int, int> MYMAP;
    MYMAP values;
    values.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
    values.insert(std::make_pair(2, 2));
    values.insert(std::make_pair(3, 3));

    typedef std::vector <typename MYMAP::key_type> KEYVECTOR;
    KEYVECTOR keys = retrieveKeys<MYMAP>(values);
    for (auto itr : keys)
        std::cout << itr std::endl;
}
```